# Is there a get_model equivalent for serializers?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I've read the docs on serializers and Googled (a lot), but haven't found the exact answer I'm looking for.

I'm trying to write a generic "archive" process (class) to handle changing a status field to "archived" for any model instance based on what's passed in the URL.

For example:

```
example.com/archive/clients.client/123
```

That would change the status to "archived" for ID 123 of the Client model.

Here's my URLconf:

```
path('archive/<model>/<int:pk>/', Archive.as_view()),
```

And here's my view class.  I had first got this working for a specific model, so I've copied that code and am trying to adapt it to be more generic.  Also, I know this needs more bulletproofing, but I'm trying to show the simplest version of my code.

```py
class Archive(RetrieveAPIView):

    def retrieve(self, request, model=None, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        app, model_name = model.split('.')

        get_model = apps.get_model
        model = get_model(app, model_name)
        self.queryset = model.objects.all()

        instance = self.get_object(pk=pk)

        if instance.status == 'archived':
            return APIMessage('That item has already been archived.', message_code='already_archived')

        setattr(instance, 'status', 'archived')
        instance.save()

        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

When I try to run this as is, I get:

```
'Archive' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()` method.
```

And that was pretty much what I expected, but I don't have anything I could actually set serializer_class to from the outset, and if I set it to None, I get the same error.  Of course, I already knew about get_serializer_class, but that's where I would need something like get_model, except that it would return the serializer class based on the model I've determined from the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are *updating* your resource, you should use a view that supports PUT/PATCH requests, which are exactly for updating properties by design (in HTTP).

[`RetrieveAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview) is:

> Used for read-only endpoints to represent a single model instance

In your specific case, you should use the most generic [`APIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#class-based-views) from DRF, since it does not require defining `serializer_class` and other properties that you wouldn't use.

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class Archive(APIView):
    def put(self, request, model=None, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        app, model_name = model.split('.')

        get_model = apps.get_model
        model = get_model(app, model_name)
        self.queryset = model.objects.all()

        instance = self.get_object(pk=pk)

        if instance.status == 'archived':
            return APIMessage('That item has already been archived.', message_code='already_archived')

        setattr(instance, 'status', 'archived')
        instance.save()

        return Response({'success': True})

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.put(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This should do the work. I've also mapped the PATCH method to perform the PUT logic, which means you can use both of these HTTP methods to update your model instance.

Now your view is as generic as possible with the help of APIView.

Comment: Wow!  Simple solution, hiding in plain sight.  Thanks for the quick reply @wencakisa.

Comment: Oops, I was a bit premature on my last comment.  Using APIView, I get "Method "GET" not allowed."

Comment: @ExTexan You can change the `put` method to `get` and it will work with GET method, but by design, GET is a read-only operation and not for updating.

Comment: Seems like it's proper in this case, though, because the class has to "GET" the instance before it can change the status.  Thanks again for the quick reply.